# UPDATED: CGAL How can I construct an edge between a vertex and the intersections of two beziers?

Tags: bezier, cgal

UPDTATE: For anyone else who find this question, and wants a solution.

After discussing this on the CGAL mailing list, it is clear that the vertex which is the intersections of two Bezier curves cannot be used to construct an edge. Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2.h does not support it.

Instead, it was suggested that I might use Arr_algebraic_segment_traits.h, which does not explicitly support Beziers, but does support general polynomials.

The original question follow:

Dumb question.

Using a CGAL Arrangment, I'm trying to construct and edge between a Vertex which is the intersection of two Bezier curves, and a point.

In this example, when I try to constuct the edge. I'm getting a segfault.
It works ok if the edge is a degenerate Bezier (the else part of the #if block)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <CGAL/basic.h>
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_with_history_2.h>
#include <CGAL/CORE_algebraic_number_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_vertical_decomposition_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Sweep_line_2_algorithms.h>


typedef CGAL::CORE_algebraic_number_traits              Nt_traits;
typedef Nt_traits::Rational                             Rational;
typedef Nt_traits::Algebraic                            Algebraic;

typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Rational>                       Rat_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Algebraic>                      Alg_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2<Rat_kernel, Alg_kernel, Nt_traits>
                                                        Traits_2;
  
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                               Bezier_curve_2;
typedef Traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2                    X_monotone_curve_2;

typedef Alg_kernel::Point_2                             Bezier_alg_point;
typedef Rat_kernel::Point_2                             Bezier_rat_point;
typedef Traits_2::Point_2                               Bezier_point;
typedef Traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2                    Bezier_X_monotone_curve;

typedef Traits_2::Point_2                               Point_2;

typedef CGAL::Arrangement_with_history_2<Traits_2>    Arrangement;

typedef typename Arrangement::Geometry_traits_2 Bezier_traits;
typedef typename Bezier_traits::Curve_2 Curve_2;
typedef typename Bezier_traits::X_monotone_curve_2 X_monotone_curve_2;

typedef typename Arrangement::Vertex_const_handle       Vertex_const_handle;
typedef typename Arrangement::Vertex_handle             Vertex_handle;

typedef typename Arrangement::Halfedge_const_handle     Halfedge_const_handle;
typedef typename Arrangement::Halfedge_handle           Halfedge_handle;

typedef typename Arrangement::Face_const_handle         Face_const_handle;
typedef typename Arrangement::Face_handle               Face_handle;

Bezier_curve_2 constructEdge( Bezier_point p1, Bezier_point p2) {
    std::list<Bezier_point> pts;
    pts.push_back(p1);
    pts.push_back(p2);
    return Bezier_curve_2(pts.begin(), pts.end());
}

Bezier_curve_2 constructEdge( Bezier_point p1, Bezier_point p2, Bezier_point p3) {
    std::list<Bezier_point> pts;
    pts.push_back(p1);
    pts.push_back(p2);
    pts.push_back(p3);
    return Bezier_curve_2(pts.begin(), pts.end());
}

/*
 * Using a CGAL Arrangment, I'm trying to construct and edge between a Vertex 
 * which is the intersection of two Bezier curves, and a point.
 *
 * In this example, when I try to constuct the edge. I'm getting a segfault.
 * 
 * It works ok if the edge is a degenerate Bezier (the else part of the #if block)
 * 
 */


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Arrangement arr;

    std::list<Bezier_curve_2> curves;
#if 1   
    curves.push_back( constructEdge( Point_2( -100,0 ), Point_2( 0, 10 ), Point_2( 100, 0 ))); 
    curves.push_back( constructEdge( Point_2( 0,-100 ), Point_2( 10, 0 ), Point_2( 0, 100)));
#else   
    curves.push_back( constructEdge( Point_2( -100,0 ), Point_2( 100, 0 ))); 
    curves.push_back( constructEdge( Point_2( 0,-100 ), Point_2( 0, 100)));
#endif  

    insert(arr, curves.begin(), curves.end());

    typedef std::list<std::pair<Vertex_const_handle,
            std::pair<CGAL::Object, CGAL::Object> > >   Ray_shoot_list;

    Ray_shoot_list                     vrs_list;
    typename Ray_shoot_list::iterator  vrs_iter;
    
    CGAL::decompose (arr, std::back_inserter (vrs_list));

    std::list<Bezier_curve_2> moreCurves;
    
    for (typename Ray_shoot_list::iterator vv = vrs_list.begin(); vv != vrs_list.end(); vv++) {
        Vertex_handle vertex = arr.non_const_handle( vv->first );
        std::cerr << "Vertex " << vertex->point() << " degree " << vertex->degree() << std::endl;

        if (vertex->degree()>1) {
            Point_2 p(1,1);
            std::cerr << "Inserting new edge from " << p << " to " << vertex->point() << std::endl;
            moreCurves.push_back( constructEdge( p, vertex->point() ) );
            insert(arr, moreCurves.begin(), moreCurves.end());
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what part is the problem? You're asking how to draw a line between two points; it feels like that can't possibly go wrong, so: is the problem _getting_ one of those points? If so, what you want to do after that is basically irrelevant to the problem you need help with, and you should focus on _just_ that part (with the code pruned accordingly too, of course)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. My question is really multi-part. I posted the first issue I encountered when trying to construct an example of what I want to do. It's really more of a philosophical question. The CGAL api for beziers only allows you to construct edges with Rational points. But bezier-bezier intersections may not be rational. So the question is whether the authors intended to support vertices that are the result of bezier-bezier intersections, and if so, what is the mechanism I'm supposed to use. But, in trying to construct an example, I got a segfault. Not supported at all?

Comment: Just because CGAL lists their mailing list as first port of call: did you also ask there? (https://www.cgal.org/mailing_list.html)

Comment: Your Primer on Beziers webpage is a terrific resource, by the way. My application essentially involves triangulating beziers, but with some custom constraints. So I want to construct the edges to bezier-bezier intersections myself in the arrangement.

Comment: I have not, but I will. Thanks.

Comment: yeah fair enough - I am by no means a CGAL expert (or novice =D) so I'm just trying to make sure your post is specific enough so that folks who are will be able to immediately pick up on the one thing you need figured out most. Also, always good to hear the primer's useful to people =)